# Matlab warning “linear inequality constraints active” when fitting ARMA(p,q) - GARCH(1,1)

Tags: matlab, arima, garch, arma

With Matlab, I specified 9 ARMA(p,q)-GARCH(1,1) models and fitted all of them to monthly return data (I used GARCH(1,1) for every model but changed the ARMA order). Here is a very small example

```
%specify data    
index = Data(:,1); %All Property

%specify model
mod22 = arima( 'ARLags', [1,2], 'MALags', [1,2], 'Distribution', 'gaussian',            'Variance', garch(1,1)); 

%fit model
[fit22,EstParamCov22,logL(9)] = estimate(mod22,index,'options', options);
```

For all of the 9 models I got the following warning message:

> Warning: Linear inequality constraints are active; standard errors may
>   be inaccurate. In arima/estimate (line 1100)

Why could this happen and what does it mean? (I only have 351 returns. Is this too less?)

Comment: See http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/optimization-settings-for-conditional-variance-model-estimation.html for a description of the linear inequality constraints enforced by the optimizer invoked when estimate is run.  A  linear inequality constraint is "active" when it is satisfied with equality, i.e., on the boundary of the inequality, at the point in question, and specifically, in this case at the optimal solution. So an inequality $a \ge 0$ being active means that a in fact equals 0. As to why constraints are active at the optimum and what it says about your data or model, I have no idea.

Comment: You can get more diagnostic information by setting options in the optimizer as described at http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/optimization-settings-for-conditional-variance-model-estimation.html . You might get more focused help on a MATLAB forum, such as at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/index/?s_tid=gn_mlc_an .